# ActiveMQ "Classic" Virtual Topic not working with python-stomp

Tags: python, activemq-classic, stomp

I config the ActiveMQ with virtual destination.

When I test the config with python-stomp the virtual topic setting never works for me.

I am using Apache ActiveMQ 5.18.2, and below is my `activemq.xml`:

```xml
<beans
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">

    <!-- Allows us to use system properties as variables in this configuration file -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <value>file:${activemq.conf}/credentials.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="localhost" dataDirectory="${activemq.data}">

        <destinationPolicy>
            <policyMap>
                <policyEntries>
                    <policyEntry topic=">" >

                        <pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
                            <constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy limit="1000"/>
                        </pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
                    </policyEntry>
                </policyEntries>
            </policyMap>
        </destinationPolicy>

        <managementContext>
            <managementContext createConnector="false"/>
        </managementContext>

        <persistenceAdapter>
            <kahaDB directory="${activemq.data}/kahadb"/>
        </persistenceAdapter>

        <systemUsage>
            <systemUsage>
                <memoryUsage>
                    <memoryUsage percentOfJvmHeap="70" />
                </memoryUsage>
                <storeUsage>
                    <storeUsage limit="100 gb"/>
                </storeUsage>
                <tempUsage>
                    <tempUsage limit="50 gb"/>
                </tempUsage>
            </systemUsage>
        </systemUsage>

        <transportConnectors>
            <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="amqp" uri="amqp://0.0.0.0:5672?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://0.0.0.0:61613?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="mqtt" uri="mqtt://0.0.0.0:1883?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="ws" uri="ws://0.0.0.0:61614?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
        </transportConnectors>
        
        <destinationInterceptors>
            <virtualDestinationInterceptor> 
                <virtualDestinations> 
                    <virtualTopic name=">" prefix="VirtualTopicConsumers.*." selectorAware="false"/>   
                    <compositeQueue name="MY.QUEUE">
                        <forwardTo>
                            <queue physicalName="FOO" /> 
                            <queue physicalName="BAR" />
                        </forwardTo>
                    </compositeQueue>
                </virtualDestinations>
            </virtualDestinationInterceptor>
        </destinationInterceptors>

        <shutdownHooks>
            <bean xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" class="org.apache.activemq.hooks.SpringContextHook" />
        </shutdownHooks>

    </broker>
    <import resource="jetty.xml"/>

</beans>
```

I am using Python stomp as publisher and subscriber.

```py
import time
import stomp

conn = stomp.Connection()
conn.connect('admin', 'admin', wait=True)
conn.send(body='123123', destination='VirtualTopic.test')
time.sleep(2)
conn.disconnect()
```

```py
import time
import stomp

class MyListener(stomp.ConnectionListener):
    def on_error(self, message):
        print('received an error "%s"' % message.body)
    def on_message(self, frame):
        print('received a message "%s"' % frame)

conn = stomp.Connection()
conn.set_listener('', MyListener())

while True:
    conn.connect('admin', 'admin', wait=True)
    conn.subscribe(destination='VirtualTopicConsumers.A.VirtualTopic.test', id="1", ack='auto')
    time.sleep(3)
    conn.disconnect()
```

I start the subscriber and then publish the message, but my subscriber never get the message.

How should I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ActiveMQ you need to prefix STOMP destinations with the type you want Topic or Queue otherwise the broker defaults to treating then as a Queue therefore your code likely fails on the send as the broker would think you are sending to a queue named "VirtualTopic.test" instead of the Topic you wanted.

- For topics the prefix is **/topic/**
- For queues the prefix is **/queue/**

Refer to the [documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/stomp) for more information